# GTK Progress Bar usage

Tags: c++, c, linux, gtk3

Looking for some details on using the Gtk Progress bar.

I have a function that I run on a button click. The desired result would be that the progress bar updates with the function progress.

```
int update_progress(gpointer userdata) {
    GtkWidget *progress_bar = userdata;
    gdouble fraction;
    fraction = gtk_progress_bar_get_fraction(GTK_PROGRESS_BAR(progress_bar));
    fraction += 0.1;
    gtk_progress_bar_set_fraction(GTK_PROGRESS_BAR(progress_bar), fraction);

    if (fraction > 1.0)
        return 0;

    return 1;
}

{...}

void on_id_copy_button_clicked(GtkButton *button, AppWidgets *aw) {

  {...}

  init_copy_job(&copy_job);
  //Scan source directory and create folders at destinations
  scan_src(&copy_job);
  //TODO: update progress bar here
  g_timeout_add(300, update_progress, aw->id_progress_bar);

}
```

I have implemented the `update_progress` callback. The progress bar updates but it is not mapped to the function. I am unsure how to do this?

Do need expose a counter in my copy_job structure? This seems counter intuitive as, what if you wanted to monitor the progress of a function where you do not have access to these variables?

Comment: "The progress bar updates but it is not mapped to the function." What does this mean? If you have both progress value and widget, you can put them together in a struct. `struct progress_t { double progress; GtkWidget* progress_bar; }`.  I think you need to put `scan_dir` in a timeout too to reflect the progress it has made.

Comment: I mean that when clicking the button the progress bar updates but it does not reflect the progress of the function. I guess the question could be rewritten as: do I need to rewrite the function to include some kind of iterator what would serve as an indication of progress? If no, and the timeout is the option. How would this be implemented? The function only needs to be run once.

Comment: Are you trying to copying one directory to another and update the progress? If so, there is already a function for that, `g_file_copy_async`.  See https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GFile.html#g-file-copy-async. GIO provides async functions for many file operations.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Yes it's a copy function, it copies data in chunks whilst feeding it into the MD5_Update function.